# Review queue edit posts mouse doesn't work

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, editor

Basically when reviewing a low quality post, if I choose to edit the item, I cannot move the cursor by clicking in the textarea. The keyboard is working fine, but any mouse interaction appears to be disabled.

The issue only appears if you review one item first, then the next item is loaded in. Editing this item will have disabled mouse input.

<s>I haven't tested other review queues yet but will do so as soon as possible.</s>
This seems to only affect low-quality posts.

Browsers I've tested:

**Broken**

- Chrome 33, Win 7
- Chrome 34, Win 7 | OSX Mavericks
- Chrome 36, Win 7
- Firefox 28, Win 7
- Safari 8, Yosemite

**Working**

- Safari 7 OSX Mavericks (Intermittent)

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome 33 on OSX Mavericks, no-repro in Safari. Can't even move focus to edit summary text box.

Comment: [Here's](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229331/mouse-not-usable-when-reviewing-posts) another user with the same general issue.  A [comment there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229331/mouse-not-usable-when-reviewing-posts#comment752669_229331) suggested it might be related to a browser add-on or user script.  No confirmation this is the problem, but if you are still experiencing this problem, it might be worth keeping an eye on that post too.

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome 34, Win7.

Comment: Reproduced in FIrefox.

Comment: Thanks @psubsee2003 I don't think it's a user scripts issue seems to only be an issue after the Ajax reload

Comment: @AshleyMedway the OP of the other question said effectively the same, so I've voted to close it as a duplicate of this since it seems to be the same issue.

Comment: Also reproduced in FF 27.0.1

Comment: fyi I have no add-ons or user scripts in Chrome

Comment: @OGHaza I installed a fresh version of chrome to check and it was still an issue.

Comment: I just answered went through 40 questions in the close queue without having the error, but on the *second* question in the Low-Quality queue, I got the error. Contrary to the OP's edit, I haven't gotten the problem in queues other than Low-Quality.

Comment: @Eric I had the issue in both suggested edit and low-quality, so assumed all effected

Comment: I will do further testing now :-)

Comment: I've been unable to reproduce in Suggested-Edit queue.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that I'm doing all of my edits on StackOverflow. Has anyone reproduced this on another network? (i.e. does this question belong on MSE or MSO?)

Comment: Does documenting this problem here count as filing a bug report? This is quite an inconvenience.

Comment: Bump...still a problem in Chrome 35.

Comment: Bumping... still not fixed!

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to reproduce this (as in: so far I haven't been able to), but I'm trying, and I do have some ideas.

Comment: @balpha I can reproduce every time on any computer, Low Quality review, complete one review, have second review load in via ajax, edit this post, cannot use mouse in the text area.

Comment: I believe you (there are enought people reporting this that it's certainly not an isolated incident), but so far *I* haven't been able to reproduce it.

Comment: Hmm, I need a clarification here. I just found that (most of) this bug was fixed a few days ago. From what I can see (which still is a bug, of course), this issue should only happen at most once (i.e. the *first* click may do nothing, but subsequent ones work fine), and even then only if you don't use the mouse to initiate the edit. Can you try again, possibly after a hard refresh on http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/review.en.js?v=fcc88b33f7e6 to ensure you have current JavaScript? Thanks.

Comment: @balpha Confirmed after clicking your link and ctrl + f5 a couple of times this seems to be working perfectly for me now

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. I'll fix the little outstanding issue tomorrow and then mark this status-completed, but be sure to let me know if it comes back after all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a bug with the popup that gives you some pre-made comments to post when deleting or recommending deletion. Since this functionality is only available in the Low Quality Posts queue, the bug only appeared in that queue. It wasn't consistently reproducible because you had to previously have had a review where you recommended deletion for this issue to appear.

That bug was fixed a week ago (it was another symptom of [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233582/delete-in-the-lqp-queue-breaks-the-scrollbar)), except for a very small remaining problem where only the *very first* click after deletion may do nothing, but only in very unlikely circumstances. This remaining bug is also fixed in the next build.