# Mouse not usable when reviewing posts

Tags: bug, review, user-experience

I've been having a problem recently (Chrome 34.0.1847.116 m, Win7) where I cannot highlight text in the question/answer being reviewed (the text acts like it is a background image), nor can I use the scroll bar on the side of the page to look further down (though I can use the arrow keys *most* of the time when the mouse stops working. The other day the arrow keys stopped working and I could only use pgup/pgdn). I can still click "close", "edit", etc, but nothing else on the page is responsive. Obviously this has never happened even once on any other site (nor anywhere else on stack overflow), or I wouldn't be asking about it here. If I close the review tab and go back to it, the problem gets temporarily fixed. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: I suspect some userscript/extension/plugin you installed in your browser. Try to disable them all and see if it's working.

Comment: I'll give that shot, and post again after some data collection.

Comment: Turning off Chrome extensions did not help, I still got the problem. Actually, like the other question, I capped out my "Close Queue" posts for the day without seeing an issue but when I tried to review "Low Quality Posts", I got the error quickly.

Comment: @Eric sounds like you have the same bug then.  I'm going to vote to close this as a duplicate so we can keep any followup discussions, comments, and, most importantly, answers in the same place.  But thanks for asking this as it likely wouldn't have received any attention if you didn't ask it