# "Delete" in the LQP Queue breaks the scrollbar

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, user-interface

I'm using the latest version of Chrome on two machines; one Windows 7 and another Windows 8.1. One has a number of extensions included, but the other has *zilch*.

---

Whenever I vote to "Delete" in the Low Quality Posts queue, the vertical scroll bar will be unclickable when the next (and all future) posts load. If I click any other action (e.g. "Skip"), this problem does not occur.

I can still use my spacebar and arrow keys on the keyboard to move the page up and down, but the scroll bar won't let me click to drag, nor can I click the arrows at the top and bottom of the scroll bar to move it.

> [image]

---

I've not seen this behaviour in other browsers (but I couldn't say I use them that often), and *only* seen this behaviour on this page (out of the *wholllllle* Internet).

Comment: Reproduced; no idea what's going on here though.

Comment: @Shog9: That makes two of us. If I'd come across a question on Stack Overflow asking how to disable clicking on the scroll bar, but allow scrolling via the keyboard, I'd tell them it wasn't possible :P.

Comment: @Shog9: Looks like actually voting to delete a post is not required: just bringing up the dialog is enough. Also, while the dialog is open, clicking the scroll bar closes the dialog. I suspect there's a stray event handler that isn't being properly cleaned up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix rolling out in build rev `2014.6.13.2312` on meta and `2014.6.13.1659` on sites.

Answer (score 5):

Aha! I found the bug!

It's in [review.en.js](http://dev.stackoverflow.com/content/Js/review.en.js), lines 4415–4417, in the function `deleteClosePopup()`, which looks like this:

```javascript
function deleteClosePopup($popup) {
    $popup.fadeOutAndRemove();
    $('.review-actions input').removeAttr('disabled');

    $(document).off("mousedown", { parent: $popup }, deleteOnMouseDown);
    $(document).off("click", '.popup-close, .popup-actions-cancel', { parent: $popup }, deleteOnClick);
    $(document).off("keyup", { parent: $popup }, deleteOnKeyUp);
}
```

when it *should* look like this:

```javascript
function deleteClosePopup($popup) {
    $popup.fadeOutAndRemove();
    $('.review-actions input').removeAttr('disabled');

    $(document).off("mousedown", deleteOnMouseDown);
    $(document).off("click", '.popup-close, .popup-actions-cancel', deleteOnClick);
    $(document).off("keyup", deleteOnKeyUp);
}
```

That is, the `{ parent: $popup }` parameter should not be passed to the [jQuery `.off()` method](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

Specifically, the extra parameter causes `.off()` to silently fail, leaving the `deleteOnMouseDown` event handler to swallow all `mousedown` events that propagate down to the document object.  On Chrome, that apparently includes any `mousedown` events on the scroll bar, making it unclickable.

Comment: That is some incredible detective work there Sherlock!